# Code first stored procedure returns only 1 record

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, code-first

I have a stored procedure `GetCountersByOutlet` which returns several rows

```
    @Locale nvarchar(10),
    @OutletID bigint,
    @Take bigint, 
    @Skip bigint
WITH countersDetails AS
(
    SELECT 
        CounterID, tto.Text as OutletTitle, ttc.Text as CounterTitle, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (Order By CounterID) as RowNumber
    FROM 
        Counters as c
    INNER JOIN 
        Outlets as o ON c.OutletID = o.OutletID
    INNER JOIN 
        TranslationTexts as ttc on c.TitleID=ttc.TranslationID
    INNER JOIN 
        TranslationTexts as tto on o.TitleID=tto.TranslationID
    WHERE 
        ttc.Locale = @Locale 
        AND tto.Locale = @Locale 
        AND o.OutletID = @OutletID
)
SELECT
    CounterID, OutletTitle, CounterTitle, RowNumber
FROM
    countersDetails
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN @Skip AND @Skip + @Take
```

Now I am calling the stored procedure using code first as mentioned below

```
public static List<CounterDetail> GetCounterDetails(long outletID, long skip, long take, POSEntities context, string locale = "en-US")
{
    SqlParameter localeParam = new SqlParameter("@Locale", locale);
    SqlParameter outletIDParam = new SqlParameter("@OutletID", outletID);
    SqlParameter skipParam = new SqlParameter("@Skip", skip);
    SqlParameter takeParam = new SqlParameter("@Take", take);

    return context.Database.SqlQuery<CounterDetail>("GetCountersByOutlet @Locale, @OutletID, @Skip, @Take", localeParam, outletIDParam, skipParam, takeParam).ToList();
}
```

The `CounterDetail` model is as such

```
 public class CounterDetail
 {
        public Guid CounterID { get; set; }
        public string OutletTitle { get; set; }
        public string CounterTitle { get; set; }
        public long RowNumber { get; set; }
}
```

But after calling the method like this

```
var x = POSEntities.GetCounterDetails(8, 0, 10, context);
```

I only get one record when I call the `GetCounterDetails` method, but the stored procedure returns several records when run on the SQL Server.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the same parameters when exec the procedure from your code?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. When I run the query for stored procedure using the C# code its returns just one value and that too the last record. By last record I mean if i ask for skipping 10 records and take 10 records then it gives me the record number 20 only.